# How to hide password from user and only copy this in original form in c#

Tags: c#, .net, password-protection, windows, password-encryption

I want to create a windows or web application to hide password from users.

Actually I have 10 third party websites with logins. I just want that the password of each website is hide(encrypt) from all users and user can copy only that password.

We can take gmail website for example. I have account on gmail. I want to give access to other user. I want to give him my username and encrypted password. He just copy that password and paste it in password field in gmail password textbox. I want to apply this on my whole websites.

Is there any way to do this? I have tested this in windows application through passwordchar property in textbox. But when I copied this and paste in website password field it can't validate and giving error. I think password is lost its original entity. How can do this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Not going to work...what's to stop someone from changing the password once they have access?

Comment: Actually I want to say that user can access the account but not see the password. If he did not know the password so how can he change the password. I have several insurance companies urls in my company. User works on them. He can access the account but don't see the password. Need to develop in windows or web.

Comment: Is this just email username and password?   Or does it include secured web sites?   If it is just email then send the email from web application or windows application.

Comment: These are Insurance companies websites. Some are secured and some unsecured. I just want to do that user can use the password but he can't see what password he is using. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

If he can copy it, he's able to access it.

There are two ways you can do this. First is to generate one-time-passwords or tokens. OR you can simply use LastPass.

> I think password is lost its original entity

This is because when you copy from a password field the original contents are not copied to the clipboard.

About Si's comment

> "Not going to work...what's to stop someone from changing the password once they have access?"

To fight this, you need to track whether the user logs in from a one-time-password or token and then simply disable any administrative features.